# Dry hop to add depth of flavour?

Tags: dry-hop

This is kind of hard to explain, but I'll try. Ive got quite a nice flavoured, mostly chinook hopped beer in the fermenter, but I was wondering if I could add another dimension to the flavour with a dry hop if I wanted to add an extra depth of flavour to it. This might sound silly, but Id like the beer to taste like it does now, but perhaps end on a slight citrus note. Is this possible to do at this stage? Or does it have to be built into the recipe.

I have some mosaic and cascade hops that might do the trick flavour wise but I dont want to ruin whats there already.

Answer (score 5):

If its still in the fermentation vessel, then yes you can dry hop.

My advise is, if you have a 5 gal Batch, dry hop a gallon of it and test it out. that way if its not what you expected then you still have your original and if it is what you expected, you can scale it up.

Then if it has your desired depth of flavor, build it in to your next iteration of the beer.

How I deal with wanting to improve my beer after fermentation, Let it be and build your next recipe with the additions. That way i can think about what it really needs.

Comment: This sounds like great advice, +1 for a test gallon.

Answer (score 5):

Dry hopping will have a much larger impact on aroma than taste. Sniff the hops you are thinking of adding while sipping the beer (ideally a previous batch of the same recipe if this one hasn't dried out yet) to get a sense of the outcome.

Comment: Ah so flavour is produced during the boil and the dry hop will mostly just add to the smell and instantaneous flavour you get on initial sip, but not to the lasting flavour? Is that right?

Comment: Yes, exactly right.

Comment: I have to disagree, Dry hop does add flavor, and can be long lasting depending on how its bottled or kegged. When I make my Lemon Honey Wheat Ale (no lemon or honey used) I use late addition/whirlpool hops and dry hops to add that citrus flavor.   The aroma fades as time goes on but the flavor remains fairly strong from 1-6 months.      Hops added to the boil add bitterness.